# How is type conversion routine of user defined objects called?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, custom-data-type

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myclass
{};

class yourclass
{
    public:     
    operator myclass() const; 
};

yourclass::operator myclass() const
{}

int main() {
    // your code goes here

    yourclass yc;

    myclass mc;

    mc=yc;
    return 0;
}
```

Who calls `yourclass::operator myclass() const`? Does `mc` calls it? Or is its call placed by compiler, based on some heuristic?

How can we see who called it?

[Object-Oriented Programming in C++](http://goo.gl/J8xrRo) says the destination object calls the routine. How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler generates the call to `yourclass::operator myclass() const` when it tries an [implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast). Basically the assignment

```
mc = yc;
```

is translated by the compiler to

```
mc = yc.operator myclass();
```

You can even call the conversion operator manually as done in the line above.

Comment: https://goo.gl/J8xrRo Please see this. It says the destination object calls the routine. It was non intuitive to me, hence I asked here. Is the author wrong?

Comment: @q126y Well yes, the compiler inserts the call `yc.operator myclass()` implicitly, if that's what you mean. Edited. But it's not the destination object that calls the routine. It is the source (i.e., the right hand side) object that has its conversion operator called. How it's done internally by the compiler I don't really know.

Comment: @q126y The destination object (i.e. `mc`) only tries to invoke its default assignment operator. The conversion takes place in the latter, as the parameter is not of `myclass` type, and the compiler kicks in trying to find a conversion operator.

Comment: The author went on to draw UML diagram with unidirectional association from destination to source, with reasoning that, destination object calls the conversion routine on the source object. Since the destination object knows nothing of the source object, and the conversion routine is called by compiler, the association arrow should be from source to destination, since source knows about destination. Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: @q126y I think the diagram is a bit misleading. The source definitely knows nothing about the destination. The author probably argued that the destination "knows" about the source since it "inspects" the argument passed to the assignment operator. However, it's the compiler that performs all those conversions, and makes the destination "happy". But the best way of understanding is probably by thinking about the compiler as an "oracle" that inserts that second line in my answer for you. To conclude, you can say that the destination object "calls" the conversion with the help from the compiler.

Comment: The source object knows nothing about destination object, but the source class knows about the destination class. Also does the destination object gets a chance to "inspect" the argument passed to it? I think the source is converted before destination gets a chance to "inspect" the argument.

Comment: @q126y My comment was "metaphoric". There is no introspection (reflection) going on. The compiler blindly follows some type checking rules and performs the conversions via implicit or explicit calls to conversion operators. In case you are interested in the internals of C++, I recommend [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Object-Model-Stanley-Lippman/dp/0201834545).  It's old (does not cover C++11 and later) but still excellent.

Comment: thanks for the book recommendation, I'll look into it.